# Laravel - How to makeHidden multidimensional?

Tags: php, laravel

There is a multidimensional array. I want to `makeHidden` the children of the array:

```
Model::with('someRelation')->get()->toArray();
```

what I get is:

```
array [
    'something',
    'something_else',
    'something2' => [
        'something_inside_something2_to_be_visible' => 'someValue',
        'something_inside_something2_to_be_hidden' => 'someValue2',
    ]
]
```

what I want to get is the array without `something_inside_something2` inside `something2`. Something like this:

```
Model::with('someRelation')->get()->makeHidden(['something.something_inside_something2'])->toArray();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you are eager loading the relationship and thus you are getting this kind of result. if you don't want that just remove `with`.

Comment: No I need that with but only some items of it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you mean, you need `keys` only.
you can do something like this:

```
$user = User::first();
dd(array_keys($user->toArray()));
```

Comment: No, specifically I need 'something', 'something_else', 'something2', 'something_inside_something2_to_be_visible'. So it means 'something_inside_something2_to_be_hidden' to be hidden with makeHidden.

Comment: Ok, you can use in your model something like this `$protected $hidden = ['something_inside_something2_to_be_hidde']`

Comment: Read, this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't want it to be hidden on all other places except this method I'm using.

Comment: Well, make it visible after the implementation of the method is done

Comment: But mostly I want it to be visible but only not here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you want to load just some columns from the relationship. In that case tell explicitly what you need from the relationship in `with` method.

```
Model::with('someRelation:primary_key,another_column,more_column')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: That's a good idea but it is a polymorphism relationship and column names are different.